# Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)- Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've got problem with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on my site created by wordpress.

The site is not working on URL : http://colin-chan.co.uk/  , but it works on test url http://www.colin-chan.co.uk.php53-8.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/

I disabled all plugins- it did'nt help. I also put a .htaccess file to theme folder here is code :

```
ErrorDocument 401 default // I found that that line may help but it didn't :(

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

What may be a source of problem ? Note that I have other site on this server and there I don't have any problems.

Comment: what's the idea behing the line `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` ? It looks like you will redirect infinitely to index.php...

Comment: Check this http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL. @Sebas, it comes by default with WP...

Comment: try re-saving your permalinks under Admin > Settings > Permalinks, I have this happen on a couple of my sites from time to time.

Comment: @Sebas, @brasofilo - That rule matches on "index.php" but the `-` substitution tells it to ignore all previous `RewriteCond` lines and pass the value through. The `[L]` flag indicates that it is the Last rule, so it actually prevents a redirect loop rather than causing one, as the last `RewriteRule` rewrites everything to `index.php` if it is not a file (`!-f`) or a directory (`!-d`). Check out [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for more info.